# How to set the permissions for SFTP user in redhat linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, ftp, sftp

We have a sftp server on our Linux server, I noticed that the ssh users are the same as sftp users, but the ssh users can be given the permissions like in `chmod` that are read/write/execute, but we want to distinguish write from delete permissions (like in FileZilla FTP server on windows which give you the control of given Write-Read-Delete-Append for files and Create-Delete-List-Sub folders for folders)

So the question is: is is possible to configure (read and delete) only permissions for sftp users?

Comment: use chmod on directories?

Comment: @Orphans using chmod will allow me just to control read-write there is no distinguishing between write and delete.

Comment: Well, if you don't have write permission on a file - you can't delete it.
Thats SSH for you :)

Comment: So, no work around or something?

Comment: I am afraid there is none yet. Because SFTP and SSH is the same. Just different name

Comment: @Orphans, can I have a formal answer for this information ?

Comment: SFTP and SSH is the same protocoll. There is nothing more to add.

Comment: @Orphans thank you, can you please answer the question so I can choose your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP is actually the same as SSH. 
Both use SSH as their protocoll.

Basically: SFTP is SSH - but for filetransfers and simplified.